Is this step in the asymptotic analysis of a certain physical system ok?
In analyzing the thermodynamic limit of a certain system in statistical mechanics, I've encountered the following situation: $f_n$ is a sequence of probability density functions on the real line with the property that if we define
\begin{align}
  \mu_n = \frac{2}{3}n, \qquad \sigma_n = \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{n}, \qquad g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}
\end{align}
then for each $x\in\mathbf R$,
\begin{align}
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma_n f_n(\sigma_n x + \mu_n) = g(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
I'd like to now show that for each $x\in\mathbb R$
\begin{align}
  f_n(x) \sim \frac{1}{\sigma_n}g\left(\frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)\, \quad \text{for $n\to\infty$}
\end{align}
So let $x\in\mathbf R$, and notice that
\begin{align}
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{\frac{1}{\sigma_n}g\left(\frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sigma_nf_n(x)}{g\left(\frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sigma_nf_n\left(\sigma_n\cdot \frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n} +\mu_n\right)}{g\left(\frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)}
\end{align}
I'm tempted to now invoke (1) and set the limit on the very right to $1$, but it's not clear to me that I can do this since for given $x$, the expression $(x-\mu_n)/\sigma_n$ scales like $\sqrt{n}$ when $n$ is large.  Are there conditions on $f_n$ that enable this final conclusion about the limit?  For completeness, here is $f_n$ for the particular case I'm interested in:
\begin{align}
  f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}n + \frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n + 1\right)}\theta\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\theta\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{(n-1)/2}
\end{align}
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

For your particular function $f_n(x)$ at $n\to\infty$
$$\frac{1}{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}n + \frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n + 1\right)}\to \sqrt{\frac{27}{8\pi n}}\left(\frac23\right)^{-n}\left(\frac13\right)^{-\frac {n-1}2}$$
Using Laplace' method
$$\theta\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\theta\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{(n-1)/2}\to\left(\frac23\right)^{n}\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac {n-1}2}e^{-\frac{27n}8(\frac xn-\frac23)^2};,x\in[0;n]$$

@Svyatoslav Thanks.  The first line I'm fine with.  The for the second line, are you referring to this: Laplace's method? I've been attempting to express the expression to the left of the arrow as an appropriate integral for a while now without success.  Any tips?

Yes, that is what I mean. Just introduce $t=\frac xn$ and consider
$$g_n\big(\frac xn=t\big)=\theta(t)\theta(1-t)t^n(1-t)^{(n-1)/2}=\theta(t)\theta(1-t)e^{n\big(\ln t+\frac12 \ln(1-t)\big)}(1-t)^{-1/2}$$
At $n\to\infty,g_n(t)$ has a sharp maximum at $,\big(\ln t_0+\frac12\ln(1-t_0)\big)_{t_0}'=\frac1{t_0}-\frac12\frac1{1-t_0}=0$; i.e. at $t_0=\frac23$.
Decomposing $g_n(t)$ near $t_0$
$$g_n(t)\sim e^{n\big(\ln t_0+\frac12 \ln(1-t_0)\big)}(1-t_0)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{27n}8(t-t_0)^2}$$
